# How to prevent a white screen when preloading textures in Swift Sprite Kit?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

This is the code I have in the viewDidLoad() of my GameViewController() class file:

```
skView.presentScene(startScene)

SKTexture.preloadTextures(BGTextures, withCompletionHandler: { () -> Void in 
    print("SKTextures have loaded.")
})
```

Since the view changes to the startScene before the preload textures is called, it will display a white background when the game starts, and then display the correct background after the textures have loaded, which looks terrible.

So instead, I made it so that it will only change scenes when the textures have loaded, however, this makes the entire app display a white background while the textures are loading... which makes it pointless to preload textures; I don't want a white screen showing (I would image this takes place during the splash screen).

How do I prevent this white color from showing?

Comment: You could try making a splash screen with the color you want the background to be.  However some platforms might not have a splash screen, I don't know what platform you are developing for, iOS, Mac, or both?

Comment: I thought about doing that but I realized that when I was using preloadTextues, it took more memory than before, so I instead not used it anymore and just kept it the old way.

Comment: do not present the scene till it is completed,  do you have something going on before presenting scene?

Comment: @JozemiteApps  That seems rather odd.  Are you trying to have the splash screen not pop up, or have it up for a very short time?  I would recommend using KnightOfDragon's way to run `skView.presentScene(startScene)` in the completion handler, but it sounds like you already tried that.

Comment: @Gliderman I meant that I thought that preloading the textures would occur while the splash screen was on, but I was wrong. I did try it inside the completion handler, but all it did was display a white screen throughout the time that it was preloading the textures. The white screen comes up after the splash screen.

Comment: @Knight0fDragon That's what I did first, but it displays a white screen while it's loading the textures

Comment: you are always going to have a white screen unless you have something prior, or you make a loading screen.  what is your intention?

Comment: @Knight0fDragon exactly, I thought that the point of a splash screen was to load things, but obviously not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to do this, one is to set the `backgroundColor` of the view (not the scene) like so:

```
self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.5, green: 0.5, blue: 0.5, alpha: 1.0)
```

You would do this before presenting the scene.

The other way would be to add your splash screen image to the view.  Basically, drop your splash screen onto the view in the storyboard editor, and add the constraints (bottom right corner of the editor) to it to make sure that it scales how you want it to.  This would allow a seamless transition from the splash screen, to the view splash screen, to your game.

I recommend calling `presentScene()` in the completion handler of the `preload` either way you choose so that the game scene appears after you load your textures.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I chose not to do preloadTextures anymore as it took a lot of memory than without using it.

Comment: @JozemiteApps Ah, okay.  How much memory did it take up?  The iPhone 4 has 512 MB of RAM, so as long as you don't take up more than half of that you should be fine (or whatever the minimum device's RAM requirement for your platform is).

Comment: Well on my 6 Plus, it went up to 0.5 GB and it kept giving me the memory low warnings. Without it, it's at 400 MB of RAM normally.